# Element intent-filter is not allowed here-Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I was adding some text editor utilities to my application. Everything was complete and the last was to write the activities to the manifest. This requires some intent-filters for the the main text editor activity but Android Studio says "Element intent-filter is not allowed here" and now i can't sync nor build the app because of this problem. Here's the part of the code that contains the activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".GrimEditorActivity"
        android:label="@string/GrimAppName"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:configChanges="locale" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.html" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
```

NOTE: This is not the main activity nor the launcher of this app, its an utility builtin. If there's a misunderstanding or help possible, please respond to the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This One:

```
<activity
        android:name=".GrimEditorActivity"
        android:label="@string/GrimAppName"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:configChanges="locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.html" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks your answer fixed my problem. Before also i followed adding the end activity tag but Android Studio keeps saying it should be a direct child of the application also when aligned correctly. But when copied and pasted your answer it was a fixed. What could have gone wrong. Anyway thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Because your activity tag is being ended only at start. You need to remove closing `/`.

```
<activity
        android:name=".GrimEditorActivity"
        android:label="@string/GrimAppName"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:configChanges="locale">  //You have end tag here.
    your intent filters..
</activity> // close activity tag.
```

You also need to add ending `</activity>`as shown.

Comment: Now At locale its says "Element activity not closed" and error still pops up, however fixed that but "Element intent-filter is not allowed here" is not fixed yet.

Comment: you need to add ending activity tag as well after your intent filter are completed.